# scp file to linux auto convert filename to utf8

Tags: linux, utf-8, scp, gbk

As we all know, Windows use ANSII to encode file name in file system, but Linux use UTF-8 by default. When I use SCP or FTP/SFTP to transfer files from windows to Linux, the transferred files will still encoded by ANSII. I want my Linux use UTF-8 only, so how can I recode the file name when transferring?
I have known there are tools to convert, but can it convert automatically when I transferring them?

Comment: NTFS, which still is the major filesystem in the Windows world I think, uses UTF-16. Can you make an example of the problem you are encountering?

Answer (score 0):

So far I only found a solution for single file transfer: To manually translate the filename via iconv before, like

```
scp $origFile user@remotesystem:c:/temp/$( basename "$origFile" | iconv -t ISO-8859-15 -f UTF-8 )
```

or use ssh and do the data transfer via stdin (allows for more flexibility, like permission modification, too).

(Direction needs to be changed for the original question, my example is from Linux to Windows, obviously).

Answer (score -2):

This is a known situation that happeds when you transfer file from windows to linux.

The utilities dos2unix and unix2dos are available for converting files from the Unix command line.

To convert a Windows file to a Unix file, enter:

```
dos2unix winfile.txt unixfile.txt
```

To convert a Unix file to Windows, enter:

```
unix2dos unixfile.txt winfile.txt
```

Comment: The OP needs to convert the filenames, not the file contents. dos2unix and unix2dos convert file contents between DOS-style line terminators and unix-style line terminators.